# Why is it not possible to cin to an auto declared variable?

Tags: c++, auto, cin

I am experimenting with C++11 features using the GCC compiler. I have discovered that the following code does not compile and I'm not sure why. I was expecting that the type of `name` would be automatically deduced from the initialisation value.

```
int main()
{
    auto name = "";
    cin >> name; // compile error occurs here
    cout << "Hello " << name << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error produced is:

> cannot bind 'std::istream {aka std::basic_istream}' lvalue to 'std::basic_istream&&'|
>   c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\istream|866|error:
>   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Tp = const char*]'|

What exactly does this mean?

Note, if you explicitly specify `name` as a `string` there is no problem.

Comment: `name` is a `const char[1]`. You can't `cin >>` that.

Comment: Try with `auto name = std::string("")`. Longer answer : as chris (and your compiler) says, `auto` seems to be resolving to a `const` variable (`_Tp = const char*]`) and you can't `cin>>` into that.

Comment: @Nbr44, Except then `std::string name;` becomes a lot more sensical :) The point was to experiment with `auto`, though, so...

Comment: The key to your question is in `_Tp = const char*` towards the end of the error message: you can't read into a `const char *` - since it's `const`, but in this case, it probably also points at non-writeable memory (e.g. "code" section).

Comment: Why don't you test your hypothesis with `auto count = 0`?

Comment: The point about `auto` is that it tries to resolve to the most simple type - which is a `const char *` (or `const char []`) for `""`.

Comment: @chris I didn't write `std::string name;`, I just wanted to highlight that what is on the right-side of the assignation is important !

Comment: @Nbr44 That's work. So I guess what I am asking is why do you have to use a different initialisation format. chris are saying that name is seen as a single character array because initialised with an empty string. juanchopanza will experiment with count.

Comment: @Skeve because `auto` will try to match with the type of the right-hand side expression. In your case, and in general, `""` is a `const char *` (or a `const char[1]`). In both cases, you are not allowed to write to them - constness ! With `count`, `auto` will match with `int` (which is okay) and in my example it would match with `std::string` (which is okay too).

Comment: @Nbr44, and everyone else, thanks for the quick responses. Do you want to turn your comment(s) into a formal answer. Just thinking - initialising name with `auto name = std::string("")` is good for the explanation but kind of defeats the point of auto.

Comment: @Skeve, You can soon do `auto name = ""s;` if that makes you feel better. `_s` is possible right now. And more technically, `""` has the type `const char (&)[1]`, but `auto` drops the reference. Soon, we'll get `decltype(auto)`, which doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you can't "write" to your `auto` variable is that it's a `const char *` or `const char [1]`, because that is the type of any string constant.

The point of `auto` is to resolve to the simplest possible type which "works" for the type of the assignment. The compiler does not "look forward to see what you are doing with the variable", so it doesn't understand that later on you will want to write into this variable, and use it to store a string, so `std::string` would make more sense.

You code could be made to work in many different ways, here's one that makes some sense:

```
std::string default_name = "";
auto name = default_name;

cin >> name;
```

Comment: Or `auto name = std::string();`

Comment: Yes, that was suggested in a comment.

Comment: @MatsPetersson why auto? when you are providing the data type?

Comment: To show that it is not `auto` that is the problem, but the fact that "empty string" translates to `const char *` when using `auto`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful to you,

```
string getname()
{
  string str;
  cin>>str;
  return str;
}

int main()
{
    auto name = getname();
    cout << "Hello " << name << endl;

return 0;
}
```